# Symfony sharing controller object

Tags: php, symfony, controller, share

I've started a project on Symfony not from scratch. 
I would like to have your feedback on a way of coding i found in this application.

The application as a lot of business classes. Some of those classes need to work with the entity manager, the translator, some data stored in the session... All objects that are available (also) from the controller.

So some of these classes received the controller object in the constructor, store it as a member and use it later in the methods. A kind of custom injection.

Here's an example of code (not complete, just to show the mechanisms):

In the controller:

```
  /**
 * @Route("/gac/print/{param}", name="_gac_print")
 * @Template()
 */
 public function printAction($param)
 {
    $printerTool = new PrinterTool($this); //PrinterTool is a custom business class  
    $printerTool->printToFile($param);    
 }
```

In the business class:

class PrinterTool{

```
private $controller;

public function __construct($controller)
{
    $this->controller = $controller;
    $user = $this->controller->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $this->userId = $user->getId();
}

public function printToFile($param)
{
    $trans = $this->controller->get('translator');
    $em = $this->controller->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    //Use those to do some business logic
}
```

};

Do i have to think about rewrite this code using properly injection or is this something that can be keeped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That what Symfony2 is all about. Use the [DIC](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html) correctly until your codebase is not to big! Passing the controller object is **really really** a bad habit. Here your `PrinterTool` service just need to have injected both the `translator` and the `security.context` services.

Comment: Thanks! The code is a big, but this can be done gradually. Except if there is any reason that this code may raise issues due to this way of implementation. But as i understood it's just a bad habit and not clean and conventional code, right?  Do you think there can be a 'good' reason to pass the controller as object instead of using injection?

Comment: That's the correct the way to go, no more no less. If you don't follow the Symfony CS, perhaps someone reading your code will just not understand it.

Comment: Ping! As no-one else answered you! ^^